# How do I make a property readonly in Monaco Editor JSON language?

Tags: monaco-editor

Is there a way to make a property readonly in Monaco Editor JSON language?  For example, make "p1" property in the Monaco Editor playground (https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-configure-json-defaults) readonly, so that it cannot be modified.

I tried adding "readonly: true" to the property itself (in https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-configure-json-defaults), and I also tried adding "readonly": ["p1"] as a sibling to the properties.

I have downloaded and experimenting with the Monaco Editor JSON language.  I had a similar need for making a property "required".  I added "required": ["a-property-name"] as sibling to the properties in the schema and that worked fine.  Like this:

```
                "schema": {
                    "type": 'object',
                    "properties": {
                        "px": {"type": "string"},
                    },
                    "required": ["px"]
                 }
```

I figured that surely there must be a "readonly" allowed as sibling to "properties", but not so.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Just bringing up the original question to see if anyone know the answer. Thank you